# Create instance from factory in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a factory that creates instance using a string id.
I will let the code explain itself...

```
class A
{

}

class B
{

}

 class MyFactory{

     private static _instance: MyFactory;

     private _map: { [id: string]: object; } = {};

     private constructor() {
        // Map the id and classes
        this._map["A"] = A;
        this._map["B"] = B;
     }

     public createInstance(id: string) : object {
         let newInstance = null;
         if (this._map[id] != null) {
             newInstance = Object.create(this._map[id]);
             newInstance.constructor.apply(newInstance);
         }

         return newInstance;
     }

     public static get instance() {
         return this._instance || (this._instance = new this());
     }
}
```

I'm a bit struggling with what should I save in the map and how should I use it to construct a new instance from that class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original example always gives a Function {} object instance because classes were passed as argument for *Object.create* instead of the prototype property of those classes:

```
//original
newInstance = Object.create(this._map[id]);
//updated
newInstance = Object.create(this._map[id].prototype);
```

This updated version would set the prototype to the correct object but
the problem is that you are using *object* as type, the compiler does not allow access to .prototype property. If you change to any, it will compile but you can't use the constructor to initialize the object:

```
newInstance.constructor.apply(newInstance);
// If in your map you had ordinary functions this would work
// but because they are classes, they result in the run time error ...
// TypeError: Class constructor A cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

A solution would be changing the annotations from *object* to *any* and then use the new operator.

```
newInstance = new this._map[id]();
```

If some kind of relation was established between the classes then other kind of casts would be applied for a better type check support. Look for the section about interfaces for constructors in the typescript handbook to see if that would fit the the index declaration for the **_map**.

Comment: If I use any for the map value, what do I set there? _map[id] = A; ?

Comment: Yes. Classes are Functions and Functions are Objects so they can be used as any other kind of value would -  **_this._map["A"] = A;_** .  Using _any_ as type of a value is not the best solution though because it gives no hint for the compiler to check if an operation on that value is valid.